# Sample conditional multivariate random variable?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, statistics, probability, sampling

There's multivariate random variable, **future** prices of assets, 5 years from now: $$X = [Gold, Silver, SP500]$$

There's historical prices for $X$ available for last 50 years. It's possible to fit historical prices to get multivariate probability distribution of future prices

$$P(X)$$

How to fit the multivariate **conditional** probability distribution? To get better prediction, as (let's suppose it is so) the **current prices** have predictive power for the **future prices**.

$$P(X|CurrentX)$$

I don't need the distribution itself, just the ability to sample $X$ given $CurrentX$. If that helps the individual prices have Pareto distribution.

Comment: Bucket by ranges of currentX

Comment: @Ezy but `CurrentX` is a vector, not scalar, how it could be bucketed?

Comment: You can bucket a vector of variables. It’s just more buckets. But you need sufficient amount of data.